# Add a string in a Bibliography Entry

Tags: bibliographies

I want to add the following line before `booktitle` entry in some `@inproceedings`. I write the line in .bib file as

`@String {Conf. = {Proc. {IEEE} Int. Conf.} }`

Then the entry is

```
@inproceedings{key,     
 title = {},
 author = {},
 booktitle= Conf. Signal Processing
}
```

I want to get the output as `Proc. IEEE Int. Conf. Signal Processing`.

Comment: You can't concatenate an `@string` with a non-`@string`, but you can concatenate two `@string`s.  Or you do it with a macro....

Comment: @jon Could you please provide a macro for me?

Comment: I posted an answer just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what (I think) you're hoping to do. You must concatenate `@string`s only with other `@string`s. But of course you can use macros as you'd expect. Compare the two entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@string{ CONF = "Proc. {IEEE} Int. Conf." }
@string{ SIGPROC = " Signal Processing" }

@preamble{ "\providecommand*{\CONF}{Proc. {IEEE} Int. Conf.}" }

@inproceedings{key,
 title = {Title},
 author = {Author},
 booktitle= CONF # SIGPROC,
 year =   2000,
}

@inproceedings{key1,
 title = {Title},
 author = {Author},
 booktitle={\CONF{} Signal Processing},
 year =   2000,
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}
\cite{key1}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I use booktitle={\CONF{} Signal Processing} with the preamble. It works fine for me. I think, should we  change the question title?

Comment: @Mithun -- Actually I think the question title is a good one. But it's your question.

Comment: Then it's OK :)